# How to mark checkboxes in modal form based on value from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, bootstrap-modal

How can I set the value of input checkboxes on a modal form from Javascript? Below is what I am doing, but the checkboxes are not being marked.

My Javascript: (the checkboxes are hardhat, boots and status)

```
var $modal = $('#editJob');
$modal.find('input#jobTitle').val(thisJobObject.title);
$modal.find('input#payRate').val(thisJobObject.payrate);
$modal.find('input#startDate').val(thisJobObject.durationstart);
$modal.find('input#endDate').val(thisJobObject.durationend);
$modal.find('input#workingHours').val(thisJobObject.workinghrs);
$modal.find('input#location').val(thisJobObject.location);
$modal.find('input#experience').val(thisJobObject.experience);
$modal.find('input#hardhat').prop('checked', thisJobObject.hardhat);  //I tried this based on other posts but it did not work
$modal.find('input#boots').val(thisJobObject.boots);
$modal.find('input#other').val(thisJobObject.other);
$modal.find('input#status').val(thisJobObject.status);
$modal.find('textarea#description').val(thisJobObject.description);
```

The modal form (in jade):

```
#editJob.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='editJobLabel', aria-hidden='true')
          .modal-dialog#popupEditJob
            .modal-content#formEditJob(action='#', method='post', name='formEditJob')
              .modal-header#header
                button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true', onclick='div_hide()') ×
                h4#label.modal-title Edit Job Details
              .modal-body
                #formBody(style='padding: 5px 20px;')
                  form#formFields.form-horizontal(data-parsley-validate='')
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label(for='jobTitle')
                        | Job Title
                        span.required *
                      .col-sm-9
                        input#jobTitle.form-control(type='text', name='jobTitle', required='required')
                        .checkbox
                            input#status(type='checkbox', name='status', value='', class='flat')
                            |  Is this job active?
                    .x_content
                      .row   
                        label.col-sm-3.control-label 
                          | Payrate (per hr)   
                          span.required *
                        .col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.form-group
                          input#payRate.form-control(type='text', name='payRate', required='required') 
                    .x_content
                      .row
                        label.col-sm-3.control-label 
                          | Working Hrs.
                          span.required * 
                        .col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.form-group
                          input#workingHours.form-control(type='text', name='workingHours', required='required')
                    .x_content
                      .row
                        label.col-sm-3.control-label 
                          | Start/End Date
                          span.required *      
                        .col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.form-group
                          input#startDate.form-control(type='date', name='startDate', required='required') 
                        .col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.form-group
                          input#endDate.form-control(type='date', name='endDate')  
                        //TODO: style the calendar dropdowns
                        //TODO: highlight required fields on posting
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label 
                        | Location
                        span.required *
                      .col-sm-9
                        input#location.form-control(type='text', name='location', required='required') 
                    .form-group
                      label.control-label.col-md-3.col-sm-3.col-xs-12 Exp. Required
                      .col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.form-group
                        select.form-control
                          option None
                          option 0 - 1 Year
                          option 1 - 3 Years
                          option 3 - 5 Years
                          option 5+ Years
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label 
                        | Description
                        span.required *
                      .col-sm-9
                        textarea#description.form-control(style='height:55px;', name='description', placeholder='Brief descrition of job duties.', required='required')
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label
                      .col-sm-9
                        .checkbox
                            input#hardhat(type='checkbox', name='hardhat', value='', class='flat')
                            |  Does the employee need his own hardhat?
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label
                      .col-sm-9
                        .checkbox
                            input#boots(type='checkbox', name='boots', value='', class='flat')
                            |  Does this job require steel toe boots?
                    .form-group
                      label.col-sm-3.control-label Other Equipment
                      .col-sm-9
                        input#otherEquipment.form-control(type='text', name='otherEquipment') 
                    .ln_solid
                    .form-group
                      .col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-3
                        button.btn.btn-default.antoclose#close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', onclick='div_hide()') Close
                        button.btn.btn-primary.antosubmit#save(type='button', onclick='div_hide()') Save Changes
```

I don't get an error message and the code compiles fine but the checkboxes are not marked, even though the hardhat, boots and status fields are marked in the thisJobObject object.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $( "input" ).prop( "checked", true ); try this to mark the checkboxes .val() will not change the checked property of checkboxes

Comment: @Manish doesn't work :( I think its because of the fact that the checkbox is on a popup/modal form. I also tried this: $modal.find('input#hardhat').prop('checked', thisJobObject.hardhat);. Any other ideas?